# trigger bool when all 9 panel have the same color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas which has empty gameobject as child which in turn has 9panels which changes color,
I want to trigger a bool when all the 9panels have the same color.

I have tried to get the Image component but it shows error: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Color` to `bool`.

Here's the code:

```
void Update()
{
    foreach(Transform child in transform)
    {
        if(child.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red)
          {
             Debug.Log("yess");
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for conditions you want to use `==` not assign it using `=`.

Second currently you are checking each image color individually but will not know if **all** the images match the color at the same time.

Using [Linq `All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all) you can do

```
using System.Linq;

...

// If you can reference these already via the Inspector you can delete the Awake method    
[SerializeField] private Image[] images;

// Otherwise get them ONCE on runtime
// avoid repeatedly using GetComponent especially also iterating through many
void Awake ()
{
    var imgs = new List<Image>();
    foreach(Transform child in transform)
    {
        imgs.Add(child.GetComponent<Image>();
    }
    images = imgs.ToArray();

    // You probably could also simply use 
    //images = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>(true);
}

void Update() 
{ 
    // This returns true if all images have red color
    if(images.All(image => image.color == Color.red))
    {
        Debug.Log("yess"); 
    } 
}
```